# Run a jar file from a java file

Tags: java, process, jar

I am trying to run jar file from a java program I found this link : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936266/execute-jar-file-from-a-java-program). I use the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("CEDDextractor_all_img.jar", "-jar", "cedd/");
    pb.directory(new File("cedd/"));
    Process p = pb.start();
```

However I m getting the error:  Could not load image: Cannot run program "cedd/CEDDextractor_all_img.jar" (in directory "cedd"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I am little bit confused with the paths I need to specify.

Batch command:

```
java -jar CEDDextractor_all_img.jar -file "file.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "CEDDextractor_all_img.jar", "cedd/");
pb.directory(new File("cedd/"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

the executable is `java` :-) (could be `javaw`, too)

Comment: Yea you are right, is java. I ve got 2 arguments which in command line is -file "file.jpg". I have to put them in two seperate args or just in one?

Comment: @FereRes The documentation for [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) contains usage info.

Comment: Yes I ve already seen it. However, I am not sure that -file "file.jpg" is one or two args.

Comment: two args, I guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect to invoke just "java", which might be not in PATH; you should use:

```
String jarPath = ...;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(System.getProperty("java.home")
        + File.separator
        + "bin"
        + File.separator
        + "java", "-jar", jarPath);
Process p = pb.start();
```