# Execute jar file from inside a Java program

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

So I've seen this question asked several times but there doesn't seem to be a consensus on how it should be done. I have a GUI where a file is created and, on the press of a button, I need to call a separate jar file, utilizing the file name as a parameter for it. Also, I'm utilizing netbeans, if there are any particularities to it and I have the source code to the jar file, although integrating it into my code would be a can of worms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run it using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java", "-jar", yourJarName, parameter1, parameter2);
```

You can pass in an arbitrary number of parameters.

As Malt described below, if you need the output of the resulting process, you can use the following code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java", "-jar", yourJarName, parameter1, parameter2);
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
```

Note that you call `InputStream` to get the **output** of the process, because you are **reading** from the stream, so it is an **input** with regards to your program, and an **output** with regards to the subprocess.

Comment: That's it? Huh.
Oh, also, how would I get its output stream?

Comment: When calling exec() You get a Process object, which has getInputStream() and getOutputStream() methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936266/execute-jar-file-from-a-java-program