# Run jar file from java program

Tags: java

I am running jar file from command prompt to copy text file from one folder to other using command.

```
java.exe -jar CopyFile.jar D:\abc\hello.txt E:\copy\hellocopy.txt
```

I tried like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java.exe -jar "+jarFilePath+"CopyFile.jar" +" "+ filePath +" "+ copyFilePath);
```

I want to execute same jar file with 2 parameters from java program.
How can use this command in other java program.

Comment: Why not just call the JAR file's main method from your other Java program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute .jar file from a Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936266/execute-jar-file-from-a-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:

```
String cmd= "java -jar "+currentDir+"\\CopyFile.jar "+inFile+" "+outFile;   
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); I want to check file is copied or not? Will this return any value => Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);