# Not able to execute java -jar command through Java code

Tags: java, windows, jar, executable-jar, ps

I have a very basic `Spring Boot` application `JAR` that exposes an `API`.
All I want to do is start that `JAR` programatically using the following code.

The problem is that I don't see any output or exceptions but JAR does not start. I tried changing the port to something that is not already bound but still won't work.

However, when I manually go into `cmd` and `cd` into `C:\LDC\dev-server` directory and execute `java -jar todo-rest-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8081` the application starts and I am able to hit the API with `http://localhost:8080/todos` url.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new Main ().executeJar(new File("todo-rest-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"));
    }

    private void executeJar(File artifact) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String jarName = "C:\\LDC\\dev-server\\" + artifact.getName();
        System.out.println("jarName: " + jarName);
        Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + jarName + " --server.port=8081");
        ps.waitFor();
        java.io.InputStream is = ps.getInputStream();
        byte b[] = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(b, 0, b.length);
        System.out.println(new String(b));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
jarName: C:\LDC\dev-server\todo-rest-app-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: I'm confused with your jarname. In your output you have `I:\LDC` but in your code you specify `C:\\LDC...` is this right?

Comment: The problem is caused because running through Runtime.exec doesn't "load"/doesn't know about all your system settings. You need to provide the full path to java. Alternatively, you can run cmd from Runtime, and then pipe in your commands.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript - Apologize for the typo. It is C:. Edited my question to reflect the correct drive.

Comment: @Sambit - That is definitely what I was looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Based on the SO link [Execute .jar file from a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936266/execute-jar-file-from-a-java-program) provided by @Sabmit, I am posting the solution that worked for me.

```
private void executeJar2(File artifact) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\JDK\\1.8.0.181\\bin\\java", "-jar", artifact.getName(), "--server.port=8081");
    pb.directory(new File("C:\\LDC\\dev-server\\"));
    Process p = pb.start();
}
```